# Combining two Points and returning not working, but adding X/Y vectors separate is?

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, math, trigonometry

Curious why my method is behaving differently than doing it manually.

Hi, I'm trying to calculate an X/Y vector (calling it angle here) in code. Don't know hot to do static methods yet, so I'm doing the following in my class:

```
private var gp:Point = new Point(); //defined at top of file
private function combinept(p1:Point, p2:Point) :Point {
    gp.x = p1.x + p2.x;
    gp.y = p1.y + p2.y;
    return gp;
}
```

In my movement method, when I call:

```
this.vel.x = this.vel.x + this.ep.x;
this.vel.y = this.vel.y + this.ep.y;
```

The object bounces around, a bit crazily of course :)

But When I try:

```
 this.vel = this.combinept(this.vel,this.ep);
```

Instead, the object isn't visible on screen.. like it got some wild velocity and flew off.

Can you tell me why these would behave differently?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Am I correct in guessing that `this.vel` isn't a Point, but a MovieClip or Sprite?  Then the difference would be that in the first example you are adding x and y values, which are members of both DisplayObjects and Points, while in the second example you are assigning the returned Point to `this.vel`, thus breaking the connection to your object.

Try this:

```
private function addPoint(p1:Object, p2:Point) : void {
   p1.x += p2.x;
   p1.y += p2.y;
}

addPoint(this.vel, this.ep);
```

p1 in this case is a reference to `this.vel`, so you don't need to return anything.

Comment: You are returning the reference to gp.  It should work the same way as returning a new Point, unless you are setting gp to null, or changing it to another value, at some point later in the script.  You could try using your old script, but declaring gp as var inside of the function, instead of making it a member variable.

Answer (score 1):

Point already has an [add](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/geom/Point.html#add%28%29) method.

```
var p3 : Point = p1.add(p2);
```